# Java 8 default method on JAX-WS interface

Tags: java, jax-ws

Recently at my work I found the following piece of code (simplified of course):

```
@WebService(...)
public interface FooService {

    /** Defaults to no-op */
    default void doFoo() {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

As you can see this interface is annotated by `@WebService` and is used as a SOAP contract. I find it a little surprising but it works and everything seems to be OK (I already checked that default methods work properly with java proxies).

Still I have a strange feeling that something is wrong here. First on the architectural level - SOAP contract should not share the code, it should only list allowed operations and their results (otherwise why to use SOAP if I can link with the code locally). Second I feel that using default method instead of adding two empty methods to service implementations (two services are using this interface) was just an overkill.

What do you think? I need some advice if I should ask the author of this code to change it or maybe I should accept this code as a working solution? Does anyone of you tried something like this with good/bad results?

PS. We are using Apache CXF as JAX-WS implementation (but this shouldn't matter)

Comment: I have the feeling that this question is a bit too opinion-based. At least there is not _one_ correct and/or good answer. Undoubtfully, there are pros and cons. I personally think, that such default methods have their place, although those default methods were primarily designed for _interface evolution_.